# width and height are zero

Tags: qt, qml

**Why do the `height` and `width` properties are zero?**

The `StackView` is copying the anchors of the parent, so it must have same height and width.

The following code :

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0


ApplicationWindow {
    id: myapp
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 640

    StackView {
        id: appview
        anchors.fill: parent
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("appview, implicitWidth="+appview.implicitWidth+", implicitHeight="+appview.implicitHeight)
            console.log("appview, width="+appview.width+", height="+appview.height)
        }
    }
}
```

produces this output with qmlscene:

```
[niko@localhost MyApp]$ /opt/Qt-new/5.9.3/gcc_64/bin/qmlscene apptest.qml
qml: appview, implicitWidth=0, implicitHeight=0
qml: appview, width=0, height=0
[niko@localhost MyApp]$
```

Qt version: 5.9.3

Comment: Hi, this has been explained in some similar question already. Basically the thing is, that your `StackView` is parented to `ApplicationWindow.contentItem`, and the initial size of this is `0/0`, until it is resized once everything is completed.

Comment: You can circumvent that, by not setting a width and height to the window, but to the `StackView` directly, or instead of anchoring declaring: `appview.width: myapp.width` and height the same.